# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. Failed to create Jar file lint-model-31.1.0.jar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a project that was developed and working fine not until I decided to upgrade all libraries and things started falling apart.

Trying to run the flutter program resulted in this error:

`A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. Failed to create Jar file lint-model-31.1.0.jar`

I have cleaned, attempted to build, rebuild, deleted `.gradle` folder, ran `flutter doctor`, restarted my system but I cannot find the cause of the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AizanSagheer I was able to implement a workaround. Some of  the libraries are not fully compatible.

Comment: I am facing  issue with firebase core, it mention firebase core and then return the same error

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur when there are conflicts or compatibility issues between different versions of libraries or tools. To resolve this problem, you can try the following steps:

1. Check Gradle Version:

Make sure you are using a compatible Gradle version. Flutter projects often require specific Gradle versions. You can check the required Gradle version in the `android/build.gradle` file. It might look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' // Check the version here
    }
}
```

2. Check Gradle Wrapper Version:

In your project directory, navigate to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. Check the distribution URL to make sure it points to the correct Gradle version. It should match the version mentioned in your `android/build.gradle` file.

For example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I  fixed this issue by following:
You need to go to android/gradle-wrapper.properties. I have this version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-all.zip
```

to this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

remember that, you need to take care of Java version in your system too.
For now, I am on

```
openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.21+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.21+0, mixed mode)
```

and my Kotlin version is:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
```

You can check compatibility and then apply the changes.

If this is still not working. Then run this command

```
sudo rm -r $HOME/.gradle/
```

This will rebuild all gradle dependencies.

If you apply all the above changes and the issue is not resolved, you can remove the .lock file in which the main folder of the lint file is present.
for example you can have

```
jar8.lock
```